# Is there a javascript template system that can be pre-compiled in nodejs and uses dom node based binding like knockout and angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, templating

I am looking for a templating system (1 or 2 way binding, don't care) that is dom node based like angular and knockout.  In other words they don't parse a string, but rather manipulate dom nodes and their contents when doing updates based on bound data.

In addition to this I need to be able to parse these templates serverside with similar data being provided (pre-rendering, like you would for a search spider).

I have searched and searched and explored many options but have yet to meet all of these criteria.

Comment: Maybe find something useful here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_templates . Otherwise, I believe all the Javascript included by `require` in Node.js compiles to V8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you thought of ReactJS? https://facebook.github.io/react/
Unfortunately I never used it so far but it sounds like it might fit your needs.

According to the description you get templates as reusable components, databinding and serverside rendering.

I hope it helps

Comment: Runs in client and node server: check.
Manipulates dom elements instead of strings: No but the level of control you have coupled with good performance makes up for this.
Live data bindings: check.

Thanks react nailed it.